# Windows 10 command to get current display device

Tags: windows-10, command-line, display

Is there any command on Windows 10 that shows the name (or some identification string) of the active monitor on a multi-monitor system? After switching to other monitor (via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, running `DisplaySwitch.exe`, etc.), the command must show the name of the new active monitor.

I'm not considering mirroring or extended desktop modes; only single-display mode.

Comment: What is the “active” display on a multi-monitor system? Do you mean the primary screen?

Comment: On a multi-monitor setup on single-display mode (not mirroring nor extended desktop), I mean the monitor where the screen is being displayed.

Comment: Is PowerShell an option?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I need this command to be called from a Java application and have its output parsed. Is this possible with PowerShell? If yes, then PowerShell is an option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `wmic` to check display device.

`wmic desktopmonitor get /?` will show all flags. In this case:

The following properties are available:

```
Property                                Type                    Operation
========                                ====                    =========
Availability                            N/A                     N/A
Bandwidth                               N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerErrorCode                  N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerUserConfig                 N/A                     N/A
Description                             N/A                     N/A
DeviceID                                N/A                     N/A
DisplayType                             N/A                     N/A
ErrorCleared                            N/A                     N/A
ErrorDescription                        N/A                     N/A
InstallDate                             N/A                     N/A
IsLocked                                N/A                     N/A
LastErrorCode                           N/A                     N/A
MonitorManufacturer                     N/A                     N/A
MonitorType                             N/A                     N/A
Name                                    N/A                     N/A
PNPDeviceID                             N/A                     N/A
PixelsPerXLogicalInch                   N/A                     N/A
PixelsPerYLogicalInch                   N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementCapabilities             N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementSupported                N/A                     N/A
ScreenHeight                            N/A                     N/A
ScreenWidth                             N/A                     N/A
Status                                  N/A                     N/A
StatusInfo                              N/A                     N/A
```

So, a sample query could be:

`wmic desktopmonitor get Name,MonitorType,MonitorManufacturer`

Comment: At first I thought it worked. But upon switching to the other monitor, the command still showed the first monitor :-/